# Android DigitalClock not displaying seconds in Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using following code to display digital clock

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Analog Clock"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Digital Clock"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DigitalClock" />

</LinearLayout>

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AnalogClock ac = (AnalogClock) findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
    //what can i do with AnalogClock?

    DigitalClock dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
    //what can i do with DigitalClock also? for display only

}

}
```

Above code working good but in Kitkat version it is not displaying Seconds please help me how to enable seconds

here I am attaching my screenshot taken in nexus 7 
[image: Screen Shot in Nexus 7 which is running 4.2.2]

Comment: Hi bro... are u working at Dharani???

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my English, Google translation. In my phone it was here.

decompile framework.jar

Add to framework\smali\android\widget\DigitalClock.smali

```
# static fields
.field private static final m12:Ljava/lang/String; = "h:mm:ss aa"

.field private static final m24:Ljava/lang/String; = "k:mm:ss"

.method private get24HourMode()Z
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 1090
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/widget/DigitalClock;->getContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-static {v0}, Landroid/text/format/DateFormat;->is24HourFormat(Landroid/content/Context;)Z

    move-result v0

    return v0
.end method
```

Method **.method private setFormat()V** to completely replace

```
.method private setFormat()V
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 1130
    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/widget/DigitalClock;->get24HourMode()Z

    move-result v0

    if-eqz v0, :cond_0

    .line 1140
    const-string v0, "k:mm:ss"

    iput-object v0, p0, Landroid/widget/DigitalClock;->mFormat:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 1180
    :goto_0
    return-void

    .line 1160
    :cond_0
    const-string v0, "h:mm:ss aa"

    iput-object v0, p0, Landroid/widget/DigitalClock;->mFormat:Ljava/lang/String;

    goto :goto_0
.end method
```